# java.swing and java.awt how to check if a button is activated or not?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Basically

```
JButton.isEnabled()
```

Is not working out for me. Once that the button is pressed I need a method to run and currently i cant check if the button is pressed or not. There were a lot of similar questions pertaining to this but none for the library i'm using or java at all, however if by chance I missed an answer please link it :) much appreciated
here is the code

```
public class main_runner extends Frame {
private static encription_algorithm ea;
private static String password;
private static Scanner scan; 
public static JFrame f ;
static Container pane;
static JLabel dir;
static JPasswordField en;
static JTextField decr;
static JButton encrypt;


// get hash button doesnt work useless needs fix
public static void main(String[] args) {


    decr = new JTextField(30);
    dir = new JLabel("type in your message to encript it");
    f = new JFrame("encryptor");
    encrypt = new JButton("press to get hash");
    en = new JPasswordField(10);
    f.setSize(600,400);
    Color c = new Color(11,45,115);
    f.setBackground(c);
    f.add(dir);
    f.add(en);
    f.add(encrypt);
    if(encrypt.isEnabled() == true)
    {
        decr.setText(getHash());
        System.out.println("trigger");
    }
    else
        decr.setText("");

    f.add(decr);
```

to get into greater detail the trigger is printing out but the method is not running when i press the button

Comment: It's so hard to tell exactly what you need or how to answer you since your question does not have much detail or depth. Perhaps you want a JToggleButton, one that starts and stops your concurrent process depending on its state, but heck, I really don't know. Why don't you clarify and expand on your problem space, and create and post a valid [mcve] so we can fully understand your code and your problem?

Comment: Here is my code

Comment: // get hash button doesnt work useless needs fix
     public static void main(String[] args) 
  
  decr = new JTextField(30);
  dir = new JLabel("type in your message to encript it");
  f = new JFrame("encryptor");
  encrypt = new JButton("press to get hash");
  en = new JPasswordField(10);
  f.setSize(600,400);
  Color c = new Color(11,45,115);
  f.setBackground(c);
  f.add(dir);
  f.add(en);
  f.add(encrypt);
  if(encrypt.isEnabled() == true)
  {
   decr.setText(getHash());
   System.out.println("trigger");
  }
  else
   decr.setText("");
  
  f.add(decr);

Comment: sorry i cant get it took look all nice for some reason

Comment: You'll not want to post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40474472/edit).

Comment: Thanks man i'm new to this :)

Comment: You've got a lot more problems there than listening to buttons. You're program is being created completely in the static main method, meaning it has no real state or behavior, other than those of the components added. Your button is doing nothing since you've not added any ActionListener to it. You'll need to learn the Swing library better to learn how to best use it, but fortunately there are decent tutorials available.

Comment: You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: thanks hovercraft :)